# Javascript Array to CSV download

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, export-to-csv

I have the data in this format:

```
var nicedata =[{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
```

each object inside it is in the format:

```
0:{1: "1", Affiliate Name: "AName", Brand1: "Bname", Business type: "Company Stores", Calendar Month Year: "mm/dd/yyyy", Category: "Null", …}

1:{1: "1", Affiliate Name: "AName", Brand1: "Bname", Business type: "Company Stores", Calendar Month Year: "mm/dd/yyyy", Category: "Null", …}
```

I want to download the data in a CSV file, I tried using alaSQL but it is not giving me the proper output.

```
alasql("SELECT * INTO CSV('DataExport.csv',{headers:true}) FROM ?", [niceData]);
```

I'm able to download the data but the entire data of a single row is being written to a single cell.

I want to download the data in a proper csv file with headers and values. Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: are you doing this in your browser? or nodejs?

Answer (score 0):

A comma-separated is not much more than a table that has been put into text. You could do this conversion by doing a for of loop that contains a for in loop like the code sample below.

```js
var array = [{
 a:'11',
 b:'12',
 c:'13'
}, {
 a:'21',
 b:'22',
 c:'23'
}, {
 a:'31',
 b:'32',
 c:'33'
}];

var csv = '';
for(var row of array){
  for(var prop in row){
    var cellVal = row[prop];
    csv += '"' + cellVal + '", '
  }
  csv += '\n';
}

console.log(csv);
```